# Error while get a blob from Azure storage (HTTP request) [VueJs]

Tags: javascript, azure, vue.js, vuejs2, azure-storage

I am trying to check if the blob with the path that I have exists in the Azure storage container or not.

this is my request:

```
let current_user_img = "https://XXXX.blob.core.windows.net/avatar/" + Img_name + ".png";

const instance = axios.create({
   timeout: 3000,
   headers: {
       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
       "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST,PUT",
       "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "x-ms-*,content-*",
       "content-type": "application/json",
   }
});
instance .get( current_user_img )
.then(function(response) {
    console.log("User have an avatar.");
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("User doesn't have an avatar.");
    console.log(error);
});
```

And the CORS for my storage is as follows:

```
ALLOWED ORIGINS: '*'
ALLOWED METHODS: 'put,get,post'
ALLOWED HEADERS: '*'
EXPOSED HEADERS: '*'
MAX AGE: 0
```

when I try to run the code, I faced this error:

```
Failed to load https://XXXX.blob.core.windows.net/avatar/XXXXXXXX.png: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `withCredentials: true` prop to your request:

```
const instance = axios.create({
   withCredentials: true,  
   timeout: 3000,     
   headers: {
       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
       "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST,PUT",
       "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "x-ms-*,content-*",
       "content-type": "application/json",
   }
});
```